# Issues updating data after insert trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am currently creating my first trigger the way it works is as follows. 
When someone inserts data on an extension table, I have the trigger fire an insert statement. The insert statement places the data that was inserted into a table. Once this is done, I have a proc that fires off that inserts the data into another table and then truncates the tables that the data was temporarily stored in.

This works great but I am now getting a duplicate key error every time I try to update, which I assume would re-insert and overwrite the previous data? I believe I have to create an update trigger as well but I can't seem to figure out the logic on how to do so. What would be the best approach to dealing with updating the data?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question. update is not supposed to overwrite data that exists, you could use on duplicate key update to update some fields but you have to understand what you want. also, the problem description is somewhat unclear, e.g. why do you write to intermediate table and then to some third table and not directly to the third table?

Comment: I'm sorry, I knew i'd have trouble explaining this. It has to do with a join I need to make in the proc to insert the correct data in the 3rd table. Let me try and explain it a little better. There is a number key that has a bunch of details associated with that number key. When I insert data into these details, I need it to look at the reference number of that number key, and insert the same exact data. I have this INSERT part working fine, but when I try and UPDATE this data, I am getting a duplicate key error.